# How to create a fake QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: c++, qt, mocking, qnetworkaccessmanager

Having a bit of a problem. I currently have a huge project that I want to test and most of if depends fully on how the QNetworkAccessManager actually responds to the calls. Since I can't really manually sit and pull out the ethernet cord just to get the result I want I would like to make a fake QNAM. Usally I would just dervie that same interface that a class dervies from and then just tell the object that is using it to have a baseclass pointer so that it can handle both the fake and the correct one without too much effort.

```
 InterfaceQNAM &_manager; // should have virtual put, post, finished() etc that both 
                         //  the real QNAM and the fake one would derive
```

However! Qt doesnt really do interface and the QNAM only inherits from QOobject and I really dont wanna be that loose with my code and just tell the class to do all the calls agains a QObject (which doesnt have a virtual put, post or anything). It would require too much code changes inside the class (casts, two different objects depending on which would we injected etc..etc.. ) How would I actaully solve this?

Had a look at the requested brach change QtMock but due to lack in documentation I havent been able to get it up and running.

Also, started to dervie from QNAM but since the methods that im using arent virtual it wouldnt pick mine up.

My class looks something like this:

```
class BaseRequest : public QObject {

    Q_OBJECT

protected:
    QNetworkAccessManager &_manager;
    QPointer<QNetworkReply> _reply; 
    QPointer<IParser> _parser; 


public:
    BaseRequest(QNetworkAccessManager &manager, IParser *parser = 0, QObject *parent = 0) 
        : QObject(parent), _manager(manager), _reply(0), _retryCount(0), _parser(parser) {}

    virtual ~BaseRequest(); 
}
```

It will then use the QNAM to do REST requests and check when it's finished.

So how would I be able to do a fake QNAM that I could insert into this code without having to change it too much? Is there any nice design patterns or anything that could solve this?

Comment: Please clarify: are you trying to obtain an alternate QNAM that seems like a real one but implements differently? If this is the case, I'd derive from QNAM and hide the "complete" functions with the "fake" ones.

Comment: @FèlixGalindoAllué I was going to suggest the same, but note that you then have to make all references/pointers to QNAMs in the rest of the project refer to the newly-derived type, else the hiding won't work. If all the source in a place where a quick find-replace works, this is a possibility.  Otherwise, this would be very very messy (if it *is* possible, it would just be a single level of messy).

Comment: im trying to create a QNAM only for testing that doesnt contain any logic but only emits signals and error codes depending on what error im trying to simulate

Comment: and yeah i was trying that but how can i force it to use the fake methods if the complete ones arent virtual? would i have to do a cast every time i use a method just to see if theres a fake version of it? feels expencive

Comment: Yes, of course. Let me clarify: You can derive to a new class, inherit from QNAM (and yes, replace on the whole project). Add a bool property named `realOrFake`. Then, on each faked function do the logic: call the original (base class) or the fake function depending on the bool. Also, add the corresponding set/get functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments at the question, let me propose a detailed answer:

```
class MyNAM : public QNetworkAccessManager
{
  bool fakedNAM; // with setter and getter functions also...
  ...
  QNetworkReply *   post ( const QNetworkRequest & request, const QByteArray & data )
  ...
}

...

QNetworkReply *MyNAM::post ( const QNetworkRequest & request, const QByteArray & data ) 
{
  if (fakedNAM) {
     // your debugging code
  }
  else {
     return QNetworkAccessManager::post(request, data);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried to do the QtMock framework but since it wouldnt build the mock QNAM in VS2010 with Qt 4.8 due to some issue they are having (they even got back to me last night). Really home this part will get merged with Qt in a near future! However, I have to go with your approach which works great for this and there's no other way atm. thank you

Comment: How can that work, if the post method of QNAM is not virtual? Where-ever you hand in your MyNAM the originals post method is still called.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest that you make your class a template and then you can override that way...but of course since you're implementing a Q_OBJECT you cannot.  No preprocessor stuff will work either.

You'll have to use multiple layers of abstraction here.  A base class that implements the non-signal stuff in your Q_OBJECT and a base class that provides the minimal interface you need to use within the QNetworkAccess thingy.  Then you can make whatever you need virtual and you can make a test version and a Qt version of either/or/both.

You might be able to get away without having to implement a base for your Q_OBJECT if you make the QNetwork thingy base you create convert Qt signals into something compatible with C++ such as boost::signals.

Good luck.  Trying to get Qt to do what you expect to be able to do in C++ is a hair losing experience.

Comment: i cant really seperate the qnam part since its used in most calls. and im not too sure what you mean. could u provide an example of some sort?